# Copy only those file who has today's modified date from a local share drive to my desktop

Tags: batch-file

i have created a batch file to copy data from local share drive to my desktop which is working fine, however my problem is that its copying all the data wherein i want to copy only those file who has modified date equal to today.

```
@echo off
title WAIT !

Set "sourceDir=\\172.16.10.55\echuser\data"
Set "destinationFolder="C:\Users\ishu.bhardwaj\Desktop\New folder
Set "_report=C:\Users\ishu.bhardwaj\Desktop\New folder"

IF NOT EXIST "%sourceDir%" (echo.Could not find %sourceDir% &GoTo:done)

:: overwrite previous log
>"%_report%" (
      echo.%date% - %time%
      echo.---------------------------------------------------
      echo.
)

:: copy files
For /F "Delims=" %%! in ('Dir "%sourceDir%\" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
   @echo.%%! &(
   @xcopy "%%!" "%destinationFolder%\" /i /y /h /f /c >>"%_report%",2>&1)
)

:done
title,Done.......

echo.&pause>nul
```

Regards
Ishu Bhardwaj

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by searching over net:

```
@ECHO OFF
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%V IN ("%DATE%") DO SET TDY=%%V
  xcopy /y "\\172.16.10.55\echuser\data\*.*" "C:\Users\ishu.bhardwaj\Desktop\Reports\SQL\CLI Dump\*.*" /d:%TDY%
  SET TDY=
```

Regards
Ishu Bhardwaj